# How do i write this SQL query in PHP and store the value in an array call $query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I write the following in php. I want to just drop the array into a variable called $query. I am very new to this.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM name_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: You should check the php manual.

Comment: What have u tried so far maybe?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM name_table"; and now Im lost

Answer (score 0):

You need to send this query to your database using database driver like mysqli or PDO.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Here is PDO documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php